# Create an .exe file of my script that is in R

Tags: r, executable

I can make an .exe file of my script that is in R? I saw it in some forums that you can do in others not. I did some tests, but without effectiveness. I intend to make an .exe file that when I double click on the file, it will run the script and apply the desired functions, however the person who presses the executable, does not necessarily need to have the R installed.

In my case I would like to show the graph. This is the script:

```
#data base
df <-structure (list (Latitude = c (-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9), Longitude = c (-49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, - 49.6, -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6), Waste = c (526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 175, 175, 350 , 350, 175, 350, 175, 175, 364, 175, 175, 350, 45.5, 54.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c (NA, -19L))
Q1 <-matrix (quantile (df $ Waste, probs = 0.25))
df_Q1 <-subset (df, Waste> Q1 [1])
#cluster
d <-dist (df_Q1)
fit.average <-hclust (d, method = "average")
clusters <-cutree (fit.average, k = 4)
plot (clusters)
```

Does anyone know how to do ??

Thank you!

Best Regards.

Comment: *"does not necessarily need to have the R installed"* is a fundamental problem, and one that I've not found feasible.

Comment: Hi r2evans, please could you take a look in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62878163/show-map-in-shiny